# With the Node URL module, how do you set all search params at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I see that you can do:

```
myUrl.searchParams.set('param1', 'value');
myUrl.searchParams.set('param2', 'value');
...
```

What I would like to do is more like:

```
myUrl.searchParams.set({
    param1: 'value',
    param2: 'value
});
```

But this does not work.

I see [in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_constructor_new_urlsearchparams_obj) that you can use the `URLSearchParams` class to do this:

```
myParams = new URLSearchParams({
    param1: 'value',
    param2: 'value
});
```

But what I can not figure out is how to use it. These do not work:

```
myUrl.searchParams = myParams;
```

or

```
myUrl.searchParams.set(myParams);
```

Nor did a few other things that I've tried. Unless I'm just going crazy, I can not find where it shows how to do this [in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You had the right thought, and it's not a typo, but you need to assign the params object to `search` instead of `searchParams`.

```
myUrl.search = myParams
```

The `myURL.searchParams` object is an instance of [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) created automatically by `new URL()`. You can use its methods, but... sadly, once that object is created, it is too late to set multiple params at once, because only the constructor supports that and none of its methods do.

It is logical to think that you should be able to create a new instance yourself and assign it to the `searchParams` property. But they decided to make that property read-only. I think this is going to confuse a lot of people, it's needlessly unintuitive.

The good news is, `myParams.search` is writable and it will happily serialize the `myParams` object.

```
const myUrl = new URL('https://example.com/');
myUrl.search = new URLSearchParams({
    param1 : 'value',
    param2 : 'value'
});
myUrl.toString();
// https://example.com/?param1=value&param2=value
```

I hope someone champions the ability to pass an object to [myParams#set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set) and that one day we can have just one `search` related property on URLs.

Comment: Thank you, yes your method works. Strange that they would do it this way, I think.